# Is it possible to use Python to make plugins for programs?

Tags: python, plugins, scripting

Or is python not a good programming language for that? If it isn't good for that, then what programming language is?

Comment: What do you mean by plugins? Python is one of the most common scripting languages for programs like GIMP etc. along with Lua, so in that sense it is good

Comment: Plugins, as in addons to programs.

Comment: addons to what sort of program?

Comment: Like OpenOffice, LibreOffice, or MS Excel.

Comment: Both OpenOffice and LibreOffice do support Python for scripting, but I would not expect Excel to (MS have half a dozen inconsistent languages of their own to push).

Comment: How would I make plugins for LibreOffice in Python?

Comment: You can also create COM addins using Python, allowing you to create plugins for Office. I would guess it is also possible to create Visual Studio add-ins using IronPython.

Comment: @YannVernier True, but MS has a single object model for the various Office programs, accessible from all those various languages.

Comment: So, is IronPython the only choice for MS Office?

Comment: No, only for Visual Studio. For Office, you can use CPython. I seem to remember that the pywin32 project has a sample Excel addon for CPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the program. There are lots of different programs (Firefox, Wordpress, jQuery...) that utilize plugins and they all use different programming languages.

Look at the plugin documentation for the program you want to write a plugin for and it will tell you what languages you can write the plugin in.

Comment: Where do I find the plugin documentation for LibreOffice?

Comment: I don't use LibreOffice or Python myself. But if I was in your situation I would use Google to search for 'LibreOffice plugin documentation python'.

Comment: @user2874670 I would sugggest starting at the [LibreOffice extension development page](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Extension_Development) which refers you to relevant pages on the OpenOffice wiki [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development) and [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Extensions/Extensions).